# Facebook Graph API / FQL - Is it possible to search for events that are in a specific country?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

is it possible with a Facebook API like the Graph API or FQL to search for events that are in a specific country?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. The `location` field seems to be a string (not a structured data field with separate country field) and it's not indexable anyway (which means it cannot be used in a **FQL WHERE** clause).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event